# Internal IP on External DNS

Tags: domain-name-system, internal-dns

We have a DEV and QA site as well as a UAT and Production.
The prod and uat are external, but the dev and QA are internal.

We have the following sites:

uat.company.com
www.company.com

I want to set up the following that point to an internal address:

dev.company.com
qa.company.com

Can I set these up in the external DNS for company.com? or more to the point, will this cause issues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it should not cause any problems, you could even use views to ensure those records are only visible when requested from your internal network

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible. I'm not sure how well advised it is, though

Who manages your DNS service? Could you go with a [split views solution](http://www.knowplace.org/pages/howtos/split_view_with_bind_9_howto.php)?

Answer (score 0):

While it should be quite possible, it depends on whether the software from your supplier allows you to configure such a thing. If you are using Linux/POSIX/Unix boxes you can overload domains using dnsmasq

C.